# Greater Than with multiple conditions in Linq Join

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL Server query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Stock s
LEFT JOIN StockOrderItem soi
    ON s.ItemNumber >= soi.StartNumber
    AND s.ItemNumber < soi.StartNumber + soi.QuantityOrdered
```

Snippet of what I got so far

```
join l1 in _context.StockOrderItems
   on stock.ItemNumber equals l1.StartNumber into StockOrderItemGroup
from StockOrderItem in StockOrderItemGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Problem here is: I cannot use "equals", it must be within a range.

How can I add multiple conditions to my "ON" clause to match my SQL query?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = from s in Stock
            from l1 in _context.StockOrderItems
            where s.ItemNumber >= l1.StartNumber
               && s.ItemNumber < l1.StartNumber + l1.QuantityOrdered
            [...]
```

Answer (score 4):

All joins performed by the [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) clause are *equijoins*. In other words, you can only base matches on the equality of two keys.

use a *compound from clause* as such instead:

```
var query = from s in Stock 
            from l1 in _context.StockOrderItems
            where s.ItemNumber >= l1.StartNumber
            && s.ItemNumber < l1.StartNumber + l1.QuantityOrdered;
```